# How to call a public method of an Activity from another Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an Android activity (Whatever.java) and I want to call into Whatever.java a protected void onDestroy method writen in my MainActivity.

onDestroy method of MainActivity.java is :

```
/** The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. */
    protected void onDestroy() {
        DebugLog.LOGD("ImageTargets::onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();

        // Cancel potentially running tasks
        if (mInitQCARTask != null
                && mInitQCARTask.getStatus() != InitQCARTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            mInitQCARTask.cancel(true);
            mInitQCARTask = null;
        }

        if (mLoadTrackerTask != null
                && mLoadTrackerTask.getStatus() != LoadTrackerTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            mLoadTrackerTask.cancel(true);
            mLoadTrackerTask = null;
        }

        // Ensure that all asynchronous operations to initialize QCAR
        // and loading the tracker datasets do not overlap:
        synchronized (mShutdownLock) {

            // Do application deinitialization in native code:
            deinitApplicationNative();

            // Unload texture:
            mTextures.clear();
            mTextures = null;

            // Destroy the tracking data set:
            destroyTrackerData();

            // Deinit the tracker:
            deinitTracker();

            // Deinitialize QCAR SDK:
            QCAR.deinit();
        }

        System.gc();
    }
```

How can I do it please?
Thank you very much

Comment: Simply change it to public

Comment: **"How can I do it please?"** : Quite simply -*DON'T*. Never define `public` methods in Android `Activities`. Also, if I read your question correctly, you want to call the `onDestroy()` method??? Never call any of the `Activity` life-cycle methods directly (not even from within the actual `Activity` itself).

Comment: In my Code I want to call my MainActivity twice in two consecutive times but due to MainActivity's complexity I face a problem to initialize my MainActivity's conditions.I use OpenGL and QCAR and my app crashes (QCAR ) problem"Failed to initialize QCAR" and as a solution in the forum of the sample app i use they suggest I call onDestroy as a solution.Please look at tripatano's answer here(https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/project-error#comment-2048271)i really thank you whatsoever!

Comment: I edited my code to incorporate onDestroy method so as to make you understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was based on the fact that I should deinitialize my resources.
I have just deinitialized my app, calling one of its already implemented methods named `QCAR.deinit();`

Thank you very much by the way ZygoteInit and Squonk !

Answer (score 0):

I have a better idea: use

```
Activity.finish();
```

instead. Calling `finish()` will ensure that `onDestroy()` is called.

It is not a good idea for a programmer to invoke lifecycle methods like `onDestroy()`. They are meant to be overriden by the programmer, and they may be called by the OS under appropriate conditions.

I'm not saying the application would blow up. Just that you should know the distinction between methods a programmer can call and methods that are meant to be overriden. That's why `finish()` is a `public` method while `onDestroy()` is `protected`.

Comment: I edited my code to incorporate onDestroy method so as to make you understand better.In my Code I want to call my MainActivity twice in two consecutive times but due to MainActivity's complexity I face a problem to initialize my MainActivity's conditions.I use OpenGL and QCAR and my app crashes (QCAR ) problem"Failed to initialize QCAR" and as a solution in the forum of the sample app i use they suggest I call onDestroy as a solution.Please look at tripatano's answer

Comment: @AugRealMan: I understand what you are trying to do. Please see my edited answer :)

Comment: @AugRealMan: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: @Zygotelnit thank you! I answered my own question...see my answer below.I solved it!